# Limit of continuous function

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove or provide a counterexample:

1) $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. If $(a_{n}) = f(n)$ converges to $L$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$.

**Counterexample:** I think this is false. Take $f(x) = \sin x$, and take $(a_{n}) = n\pi$, then $(a_{n}) \rightarrow 0$, but the limit of $f(x) \neq 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

2) If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = -\infty$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} |f(x) + g(x)|$ DNE.

**Counterexample:** I think this is also false. Take $f(x) = \ln x$, and $g(x) = -\ln x$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} |f(x) + g(x)| = 0$?

3) If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} |f(x) \cdot g(x)|$ DNE.

**Counterexample(?):** Is this also false? Let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} |f(x) \cdot g(x)|$  = 1. Although I'm not quite sure if you can take the limit of a horizontal line? For 2) and 3)

Comment: All your answers are okay, depending perhaps on how much detail is expected. You can definitely take the limit of a constant function.